# Split the values of a Tag using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Source:

```
  <Data>
     <value>M1,M2,M3,M4,M5,M6</value>
  </Data>
```

Need to Display them as

Output:

```
    <ABCD>
        <value1>M1</value1>
        <value2>M2</value2>
        <value3>M3</value3>
        <value4>M4</value4>
        <value5>M5</value5>
        <value6>M6</value6>
    </ABCD>
```

XSLT:

I actually want to split the value based on "," and place them in different variables.
Using str-split(), Can I load it in different variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <ABCD>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </ABCD>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="value/text()" name="split">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
  <xsl:param name="pOrd" select="1"/>

  <xsl:if test="$pText">
    <xsl:element name="value{$pOrd}">
      <xsl:value-of select=
        "substring-before(concat($pText, ','), ',')"/>
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:call-template name="split">
      <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, ',')"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="pOrd" select="$pOrd+1"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Data>
    <value>M1,M2,M3,M4,M5,M6</value>
</Data>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<ABCD>
   <value1>M1</value1>
   <value2>M2</value2>
   <value3>M3</value3>
   <value4>M4</value4>
   <value5>M5</value5>
   <value6>M6</value6>
</ABCD>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Recursive named template, with stop-condition when the passed text-parameter becomes the empty string.
2. Proper use of **[`xsl:element`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#section-Creating-Elements-with-xsl%3aelement)** and **[AVT](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates)**.
3. Proper use of the standard XPath functions **[`substring-before()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-before)** and **[`substring-after`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-after)**
4. Proper use of a **[sentinel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value)** to simplify the code and make it more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to EXSLT you can use `str:split()`.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select='str:split(/Data/value, ",")' />
```

[Runnable example here](http://www.xmlplayground.com/mV69jJ)